# Twisted module textbook

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, book-recommendation

I study algebraic geometry with hartshorne's book.
Now, I reached to the section 2.5 which is about sheaves of module.
I cannot understand the twisted structure.
Can you recommend any textbook covers twisted module?

Comment: Have you tried Gortz-Wedhorn?

Comment: No, I wanted to find it. But my university doesn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

See page  50 of  Robin Hartshorne's $\textit{Algebraic Geometry}$. For  your  convenience, I have attached screenshot.
[image]

Comment: I found that before but I want more about it.